# how to sort list of object? OrderBy c#

Tags: c#

I have `Track` class

```
class Track
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Double Duration;
    public Boolean IsRemix;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (IsRemix) return Name + "(Remix) " + Duration;
        return Name + " " + Duration;
    }
}
```

and `Album` is a List:

```
class Album :List<Track>
    {
        public Album SortByAlphabet()
        {
            return new Album().OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
        }
    }
```

How can I order Album by Track's name? In SortByAlphabet I need only Album be output.

**Edit**

```
return this.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

and

```
return (Album)this.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

doesn't help

it's
throwing an exception, InvalidCastException

Comment: I would recommend not inheriting from `List<>`. You can find more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt).

Comment: `OrderBy()` doesn't sort the collection, it iterates over the collection in sorted order.  If you want to sort your list, call [`Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)... that's why it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not suggest inheriting from List, but if you do, the following should meet your requirement:

```
class Album : List<Track>
{
    public Album() : base() { }

    public Album(IEnumerable<Track> tracks) : base(tracks) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sort in place the album of tracks alphabetically by name 
    /// </summary>
    public void SortByAlphabet()
    {
        Sort((t1, t2) => t1.Name.CompareTo(t2.Name));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a new Album with tracks sorted alphabetically by name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Album OrderByAlphabet()
    {
        return new Album(this.OrderBy(t => t.Name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider suggesting specifying `String.Compare()` and allowing for a culture sensitive comparison. I certainly share your concern about an `Album` serving as ` List`, a sorter, and a `Comparer`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't inherit from `List<T>`. [You aren't making a list, you're making an album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle).

An album has a list of songs, and you can represent this with a member. It uses your implementation of `Track` (I'd honestly not use `Boolean`, `Double`, etc. and not have bare public fields, but that's another discussion.)

```
class Album {
  private readonly List<Track> _tracklist;
  public ReadOnlyCollection<Track> Tracklist {
    get {
      return new ReadOnlyCollection<Track>(_tracklist);
    }
 }

  public Album(IEnumerable<Track> tracklist) {
    _tracklist = new List<Track>(tracklist);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var album = new Album(new List<Track> {
  new Track { Name = "Blonde"}, 
  new Track { Name = "K.-O."}, 
  new Track { Name="Alcaline"}, 
  new Track { Name="Seulement pour te plaire"}, 
  new Track { Name="L'amour renfort"},
  new Track { Name="Bi"},
  new Track { Name="Mon planeur"},
  new Track { Name="Ce qui tue l'amour"},
  new Track { Name="Tweet"},
  new Track { Name="Charles est stone"},
  new Track { Name="Mylène Farmer"},
  new Track { Name="Plus de bye bye"}
});

var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
var tracks = album.Tracklist.OrderBy(t => t.Name, StringComparer.Create(culture, false));
tracks.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Output:

```
Alcaline 0
Bi 0
Blonde 0
Ce qui tue l'amour 0
Charles est stone 0
K.-O. 0
L'amour renfort 0
Mon planeur 0
Mylène Farmer 0
Plus de bye bye 0
Seulement pour te plaire 0
Tweet 0
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
class Album : List<Track>
{
    public Album SortByAlphabet()
    {
        return (Album)(this.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList());
    }
}
```

Comment: throwing an exception, InvalidCastException